# Virtual Machine Manager Service upgrade Issue - Web deploy fails to delete directory

Tags: webdeploy, system-center

I have an issue with simple service upgrade. My service has one tire and it has a web application.

When I try to upgrade the service, the following error occurred.

```
`Application (C:\ProgramData\VirtualMachineManagerData\CacheResources\779b4f72f2a647e2b6dc119f20e0da25\BusinessCenter_Package_v0.0.0.57.zip, WebDeploy) removal failed on the virtual machine (HBC_STAG_VM_01). DetailedErrorMessage: An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete Directory' on 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content'.`
```

Then I have added a web deploy configuration file msdeploy.exe.configsettings with following contents to disable two webdeploy rules.

```
<configuration>
  <rules>
    <rule name="BlockHarmfulDeleteOperations" enabled="false" />
    <rule name="BlockUnsupportedDeleteOperations" enabled="false" />
  </rules>
</configuration>
```

Now I am getting following error.

```
`Application (C:\ProgramData\VirtualMachineManagerData\CacheResources\a9483ef219134b75bf1422774b3efdcb\BusinessCenter_Package_v0.0.0.59.zip, WebDeploy) removal failed on the virtual machine (HBC_STAG_VM_01). DetailedErrorMessage: Provider setAcl is blocked, by BlockUnsupportedDeleteOperations, from performing delete operations to avoid unexpected results.`
```

I never able to successfully upgrade a service. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Sapumal.